# pct_change function in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to calculate percentage change of values in value column for each ID separately in a new pct_change column. Example df below.

Some sources in the internet say that there is a pct_change() function available in pyspark 2.4+  which would make this easy but I am on 3.0.1 and I am not able to import it from pyspark.sql.functions.

```
   ID   value pct_change 
    1     1      nan
    1     2       1
    1     4       1
    2     1      nan
    2     1       0
    2    0.5    -0.5
    3     5      nan
    3     5       0
    3     7      0.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Window function in pyspark

Code and logic below

```
w =Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('index')#.rowsBetween(-1,0)


(df.withColumn('index', monotonically_increasing_id())#Create an index to OrderBy
 .withColumn('pct_change', (col('value')-lag('value').over(w))#Calculate change in consecutive rows
  /lag('value').over(w))#Find rate of change in consecutive row
 .drop('index')#Drop the ordering column
).show()


+---+-----+----------+
| ID|value|pct_change|
+---+-----+----------+
|  1|  1.0|      null|
|  1|  2.0|       1.0|
|  1|  4.0|       1.0|
|  2|  1.0|      null|
|  2|  1.0|       0.0|
|  2|  0.5|      -0.5|
|  3|  5.0|      null|
|  3|  5.0|       0.0|
|  3|  7.0|       0.4|
+---+-----+----------+
```